# problem with return type in typescript with optional indexer

Tags: typescript

In the following example I want to type the return type of a function:

```
type MakeNamespace<T> = T & { [index: string]: T }

export interface INodeGroupProps<T = unknown[], State = {}> {
  data: T[];
  start: (data: T, index: number) =>  MakeNamespace<State>;
}

export interface NodesState {
  top: number;
  left: number;
  opacity: number;
}

export type Point = { x: number, y: number }

const points: Point[] = [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 2, y: 3 }]

const Nodes: INodeGroupProps<Point, NodesState> = {
  data: points,
  keyAccessor: d => {
    return d.x
  },
  start: point => {
    return {
      top: point.y,
      left: point.x,
      opacity: 0,
    }
  }
}
```

The return type of the `start` function could be:

```
    return {
      top: point.y,
      left: point.x,
      opacity: 0
    }
```

or it could be:

```
return {
  namespace1: {
    top: point.y,
    left: point.x,
    opacity: 0
  },
  namespace2: {
    top: point.y,
    left: point.x,
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

My code will not allow this and typescript complains:

> Property 'top' is incompatible with index signature

Changing `MakeNamespace` to `type MakeNamespace<T> = T | { [index: string]: T }` works but won't cover this case:

```
const Nodes: INodeGroupProps<Point, NodesState> = {
  data: points,
  start: point => {
    return {
      top: point.y,
      left: point.x,
      opacity: 0
      namespace1: {
        top: point.y,
        left: point.x,
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where i have a combination of both.

Due to return type widening, I lose type safety on the `namespace` key because it is going for the `T` part of the union.

My thoughts would be to make the indexer optional but I am not sure how to do that.

Here is a [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20MakeNamespace%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bindex%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20INodeGroupProps%3CT%20%3D%20unknown%5B%5D%2C%20State%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20data%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20start%3A%20(data%3A%20T%2C%20index%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20%20MakeNamespace%3CState%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20NodesState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20top%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20left%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20opacity%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20Point%20%3D%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20points%3A%20Point%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20x%3A%200%2C%20y%3A%200%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20x%3A%201%2C%20y%3A%202%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20x%3A%202%2C%20y%3A%203%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20Nodes%3A%20INodeGroupProps%3CPoint%2C%20NodesState%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20data%3A%20points%2C%0D%0A%20%20keyAccessor%3A%20d%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20d.x%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20start%3A%20point%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20top%3A%20point.y%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20left%3A%20point.x%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20opacity%3A%200%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: can you do it in another way? instead of having `namespace` as a key. return it as an array that contains namespace inside

Comment: Shouldn't `timing` be an error everywhere? You seem to want `MakeNamespace<T>` to be the same as `T` but with possibly extra properties whose values are themselves of type `T`. But `timing` is not a key of `NodesState` and `{ duration: 500 }` is not compatible with `NodeState` so I don't know if I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: And I'm seeing an `opacity: '0'` in there instead of `opacity: 0`.  I'm guessing these are just typos or something but it gets in the way of trying to answer this.

Comment: oops yes, that is a typo

Comment: So you edited `opacity`, but is `timing` supposed to be a property of `NodeState`?

Comment: apologies, I've removed timing, that is from the real example.   Confusing for it to be there

Comment: Would this work `export type MakeNamespace<T extends {}> = {[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends T ? {[index: string]: T} : T[P] };`

Comment: no, it wouldn't add any extra keys to `T`, sorry.  The only way to represent that type in TS is to do something like `MakeNamespace<T, K extends keyof any>` where `K` is the extra key set and do inference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in control of enough code to change the design to something more TypeScript-friendly, that would be my suggestion.  For example, if you place the extra namespaces in a single property with a known name, it will be much simpler to describe the type (note that I'm going to remove code and types that are not relevant to the issue, such as the `INodeGroupProps['data']` property):

```
// add an optional "namespaces" property which is itself a bag of T
type MakeNamespace<T> = T & { namespaces?: { [k: string]: T | undefined } };

export interface INodeGroupProps<T, State> {
  start: (data: T, index: number) => MakeNamespace<State>;
}

export interface NodesState {
  top: number;
  left: number;
  opacity: number;
}

export type Point = { x: number, y: number }

// okay
const Nodes: INodeGroupProps<Point, NodesState> = {
  start: (point: Point) => {
    return {
      top: point.y,
      left: point.x,
      opacity: 0,
    }
  }
};

// also okay
const Nodes2: INodeGroupProps<Point, NodesState> = {
  start: (point: Point) => {
    return {
      top: point.y,
      left: point.x,
      opacity: 0,
      namespaces: {
        namespace1: {
          top: point.y,
          left: point.x,
          opacity: 0,
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

That still has the issue of widening the return type to `INodeGroupProps<Point, NodesState>` so the compiler will forget, for example, that `Nodes2.namespaces.namespace1` exists:

```
const ret = Nodes2.start({ x: 1, y: 2 }, 0);
const oops = ret.namespaces.namespace1; // error! possibly undefined?
if (ret.namespaces && ret.namespaces.namespace1) {
  const ns = ret.namespaces.namespace1; // okay, ns is NodeState now
} else {
  throw new Error("why does the compiler think this can happen?!")
}
```

Generally the way around this is to change your possibly-too-wide type annotations to calling a helper function which requires that the value matches the annotation, but does not widen to it.  Like:

```
const ensure = <T>() => <U extends T>(x: U) => x;

const ensureRightNodes = ensure<INodeGroupProps<Point, NodeState>>();


const Nodes = ensureRightNodes({
  start: (point: Point) => {
    return {
      top: point.y,
      left: point.x,
      opacity: 0,
    }
  }
});

const Nodes2 = ensureRightNodes({
  start: (point: Point) => {
    return {
      top: point.y,
      left: point.x,
      opacity: 0,
      namespaces: {
        namespace1: {
          top: point.y,
          left: point.x,
          opacity: 0,
          timing: { duration: 500 }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

// Now Nodes and Nodes2 are narrowed:

const ret = Nodes2.start({ x: 1, y: 2 }); // Nodes2.start takes ONE param now
const ns = ret.namespaces.namespace1; // okay, ns is NodesState.
```

There are benefits to both widening and narrowing (widening: `Nodes2.start()` will accept two parameters as defined in `INodeGroupProps`; narrowing: `Nodes2.start(p).namespaces.namespace1` is known to exist) so it's a tradeoff and it's up to you to figure out where the right balance is for your needs.

---

Backing up, it's possible you might need to keep the original "`T` plus all sorts of extra properties" definition, and in that case you can coax and cajole the compiler to accepting it using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types), with the same caveats about narrowing as above:

```
type MakeNamespace<T, K extends keyof any> = T & Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, T>;

export interface INodeGroupProps<T, State, K extends keyof any> {
  start: (data: T, index: number) => MakeNamespace<State, K>;
}

type ExtraKeysFromINodeGroupProp<T, State, N> =
  N extends INodeGroupProps<any, any, any> ?
  Exclude<keyof ReturnType<N['start']>, keyof State> : never

type InferINodeGroupProp<T, State, N> =
  INodeGroupProps<T, State, ExtraKeysFromINodeGroupProp<T, State, N>>;

const inferNodeGroupPropsFor = <T, State>() =>
  <N>(ingp: N & InferINodeGroupProp<T, State, N>):
    InferINodeGroupProp<T, State, N> => ingp;

const ngpPointNodesState = inferNodeGroupPropsFor<Point, NodesState>();

const Nodes = ngpPointNodesState({
  start: (point: Point) => {
    return {
      top: point.y,
      left: point.x,
      opacity: 0,
    }
  }
});

const Node2 = ngpPointNodesState({
  start: (point: Point) => {
    return {
      top: point.y,
      left: point.x,
      opacity: 0,
      namespace1: {
        top: point.y,
        left: point.x,
        opacity: 0,
      }
    }
  }
});


Node2.start({ x: 1, y: 1 }, 0).namespace1.left; // okay
```

To get that working you need to make `MakeNamespace` generic enough to represent *which* extra keys `K` you are adding, and then do all kinds of things to verify that a passed-in value matches `INodeGroupProps<T, State, K>` for some `K` that you extract from the value's type.  It's frankly a mess... so if possible I'd really recommend trying not to go the dynamic-extra-properties route.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm not in charge of the code so `namespaces` won't work unfortunately.  The last example is probably a bit much but agin, very interesting